# How to make Dockerfile COPY work for windows absolute paths?

Tags: dockerfile, docker-for-windows

How do I make my **COPY** command work for absolute paths on Windows? I tried git-bash, cmd and powershell consoles to build with `docker build -t custom-maven-image .`

```dockerfile
# Dockerfile
FROM maven:3-openjdk-11-slim
# these are three versions of copy command I tried
COPY C:/Users/myuser/.m2 /root/.m2
COPY /C/Users/myuser/.m2 /root/.m2
COPY /c/Users/myuser/.m2 /root/.m2
```

What I get is an error:

```
...
#5 ERROR: "/C/Users/myuser/.m2" not found: not found
```

UPDATE:

Thx @Jeremy for bugs references and now I see that [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) clearly says:

> COPY obeys the following rules:
>
> The  path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot
> COPY ../something /something, because the first step of a docker build
> is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker
> daemon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the resources need to be in the dir that you run the build, i.e. where your Dockerfile is. You cant use an absolute path from elsewhere, think of it from the build perspective - where is the build happening - in the Dockerfile? It can run commands but those resources need to be public.

- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4592
- https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4857

Comment: Can you support that with some docs? What about relative paths, e.g. `../../mypath/`?

Comment: Yeah relative are fine if they are in the directory - but its a container, it cant reach outside that to somewhere in your system. Hope that makes sense, fairly new to it myself, but know that it needs to be in the right context.